# How to download a file browser in Python+Webkit+Gtk?

Tags: python, download, webkit, gtk, pygtk

Here is a simple browser in Python Webkit Gtk:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gtk
import webkit

view = webkit.WebView()
sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()

sw.add(view)

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

win.add(sw)

win.show_all()

view.open("https://www.kernel.org/")

gtk.main()
```

Browsing works perfectly. Unfortunately, it does not work to save files on the local computer. I could not find a ready solution. I do not need a progress bar, folder selection, I want to click on the link resulted in downloading. Do you know the easiest way to save files to the directory /home/user?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you should be using pygobject and webkit2gtk. The old pygtk versions are not supported and that version of webkit is very insecure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the [docs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#WebKit-3.0/classes/WebView.html#WebKit.WebView.signals.download_requested), you have to connect to the `mime-type-policy-decision-requested` and `download-requested` signals.

```
view.connect('download-requested', download_requested)
view.connect('mime-type-policy-decision-requested', policy_decision_requested)
```

Then you check the mime-type and decide if you want to download it:

```
def policy_decision_requested(view, frame, request, mimetype, policy_decision):
    if mimetype != 'text/html':
        policy_decision.download()
        return True
```

When `download-requested` is emitted afterwards, you can let the `WebKit.Download` object handle the download or (in this case) do it with python:

```
def download_requested(view, download):
    name = download.get_suggested_filename()
    path = os.path.join(
        GLib.get_user_special_dir(GLib.UserDirectory.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD),
        name
    )
    urlretrieve(download.get_uri(), path)  # urllib.request.urlretrieve
    return False
```