# Unable to Download link from WebKit

Tags: python, webkit, pygtk

I am developing a Browser in pygtk using webkit.
 I want to use the inbuilt download manager in webkit.
Currently, if i click on any downlaod link then the download gets automatically cancelled since i have no function connected to handle the signal.
I am trying to use this as a reference https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitDownload.html

I am new to Software development and not sure as to how to use the functions in the given link above.
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are confused about the C functions, rather look at the python [docs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#WebKit2-4.0/classes/Download.html#webkit2-download)

Comment: @elya5, i am using python. But i am unable to do that Can you give me an example code or some reference for it?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503714/how-to-download-a-file-browser-in-pythonwebkitgtk/41522553#41522553) help you?